# Unable to execute Stored Procedure through SSMS and VS

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, permissions

I have a stored proc which just updates a table and I am executing it through C# code as well as through SSMS. Whenever i execute it, I get the following error:

> Login failed for user domain\username

I have given full permissions to the SP and have also recreated the SP, but still I get the error. Strange thing is, all other procedures are working fine from both C# code and SSMS. I have also provided sysadmin access to my ID - still no luck.

While executing from VS (C# code), the connection opens but getting the same exception (SQLException).

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this error?

Comment: You stored procedure is failing because the user in your connection string cannot login to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gregg for your suggestion. I have fixed this error. The problem was with the underlying tables the procedure was using and I have dropped and created those tables. Bingo.- it worked.
Looks strange but this is how I fixed.